# Flag enum speed vs booleans?

Tags: c#, enums

```
[Flags]
enum Flaggy { None = 0, A=1, B=2, C=4, D=8}

Flaggy test;
```

or

```
bool A, B, C, D;
```

Is the flagged enum more efficient than the booleans or does it not really matter? In terms of cpu?

EDIT:
Yes I know that [Flags] doesn't really do anything compared to a non-flags enums aside from adding a .ToString() method and some readability. Well, this piece of code is checked like 25000+ times per second so even a micro gain would be worth it. But a Flags Enum is nicer to read in the code compared to like 20 booleans and with .NET 4.0 the HasValue() makes up for the previously annoying checking for the Flags-values. But a method call in stead of an if-check is another micro cpu drain.
But reading the answers that came so quickly I guess it's more a choice of readability than performance.

Comment: This is something you need to worry about if you have performance problems and your testing and profiling has shown that it is the issue. Micro optimizing like this is not normally beneficial.

Comment: Isn't the attribute called [Flags]?

Comment: `A, B, C, D` is **not** correct for `[Flags]` - needs to be `A=1, B=2, C=4, D=8`

Comment: Ah oops yes I forgot that [Flags] doesn't add that automatically...

Comment: You have two horses. You want to know which one is faster. So you ask strangers on the internet?  I would *run a race*. If you want to know which technique is faster, *try both*, get out a stopwatch, and pretty soon you'll know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flagged enum will be backed as a single Int32 in memory whereas the booleans will be stored as separate Boolean variables. So both will occupy the same memory.

In terms of CPU, with the enum you will need to perform bitwise operations to determine the values whereas with the booleans it's a simple `if` so I guess it will be slightly faster. But that's a premature optimization that you shouldn't be concerned at all with. Both will be fast enough so pick the one that makes your code more readable.

Comment: Of course, you could declare the enum with `byte` as the underlying type, if storage is a significant consideration.

Answer (score 2):

First off AFAIK there is no `[Flagged]` - best guess would be that you mean `[Flags]`, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx).

Whether it is faster in terms of CPU time depends very much on what exactly you do with them... but I think this is "micro optimization" (which is usually a bad idea)... run the code with a profiler and see where the bottlenecks really before guessing where/what to optimize...

Answer (score 2):

I prefer flags instead of boolean in this case, sure performance is not much difference and doing bit optimization is not good because it will reduce code readability and code maintenance.